# How to get consolidated Cucumber report if 5 jobs are running parellelly

Tags: azure, pipeline, agent

Current Scenario: We have 5 jobs in RT executions and each job is running on 5 different agents. So we have 5 cucumber reports.

Expected Scenario: We need a consolidated Cucumber HTML Report of all 5 jobs.

How it can be resolved? We are working in azure Devops.

Answer (score -1):

The Cucumber Html report is a single page html application. If you open it up in an editor you'll see that it contains a an array of messages.

These messages can also be obtained by using the `messages:target/messages.ndjson` plugin. If you can obtain in a single job the messages from each parallel job you can then merge these and pass them to the [html-formatter](https://github.com/cucumber/html-formatter).

To merge the files you may have to filter out some messages. Definitively requires writing some code, don't think anyone has done this before, but shouldn't be impossible.

Comment: Can u please help me out?                 Where I have to add these messages plugin?

Comment: The same place you'd configure other plugins like the html report or pretty formatter. How depends on how you run cucumber

Comment: As for everything else, you'll have to work that out yourself. Try and understand how the whole system works, it will help.